# Laravel-4 Pagination in Query Builder

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-4

How to enable pagination in laravel-4.1 when using query builder.

Here is my function from model.

```
public static function getTransactions( $accountCode ) {
        $accountId = Account::getAccountId( $accountCode );
        $object = DB::table('transactions')
            ->orderBy('transactionId', 'ASC')
            ->where('fkAccountId', $accountId)
            ->where('fkUserId', Auth::user()->userId);
            ->get();

        return $object;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static function getTransactions( $accountCode ) {
        $accountId = Account::getAccountId( $accountCode );
        $object = DB::table('transactions')
            ->orderBy('transactionId', 'ASC')
            ->where('fkAccountId', $accountId)
            ->where('fkUserId', Auth::user()->userId);
            ->paginate(10);

        return $object;
    }
```

and

```
echo $object->links(); //links
```

http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage

Comment: Actually , this is not good answer because you will lost your order when you open next page

Answer (score 3):

```
   public static function getTransactions( $accountCode ) {
        $accountId = Account::getAccountId( $accountCode );
        $object = DB::table('transactions')
            ->orderBy('transactionId', 'ASC')
            ->where('fkAccountId', $accountId)
            ->where('fkUserId', Auth::user()->userId);
            ->paginate(NUMBER OF PAGES); // whatever you needs this to be

        return $object;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you accede to your model via your controller before returning the view, make :

```
abstract class YourController extends \BaseController {
    public function index() {
        $modelManager = new yourModel();
        $pagination = $modelManager->getTransactions($accountCode)->links();

        return View::make('yourView', array('pagination' => $pagination));
    }
}
```

and use `{{$pagination}}` in your view.